# Do I need to configure c3p0 connection pooling for Amazon RDS service?

Tags: hibernate, amazon-web-services, c3p0

I have an Amazon Beanstalk application using hibernate connecting to an Amazon Relational Database Service db.

I'm wondering if I need to configure the c3p0 connection pooling myself or RDS already takes care of that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS is exposed as a web-service. Database connection pooling (with c3p0) is needed when the application has the connection object with itself, which is not the case here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you do mean by application having connection object with itself?

Comment: c3p0 is a database connection pooling software. An application interacts with RDS through HTTP connections. 

Thus RDS will handle this and your application need not bother.